# A better way to intercept property updates from UI using EF and MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF application with an undo-redo functionality. I use EF to interact with the database.

I would like to know if there is a better approach or pattern to be notified when the UI changes some property.

Here is the approach I currently use:

- Let EF generate the class. For example:

  ```
  public partial class Page: IObjectWithChangeTracker, INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
  #region Primitive Properties

  [DataMember]
  public string title
  {
      get { return _title; }
      set
      {
          if (_title != value)
          {
              _title = value;
              OnPropertyChanged("title");
          }
      }
  }
  private string _title;

  ...
  ```
- Then in the non-generated part of the class, I add another property for the UI. In this particular case, the property is bound to a WPF TextBox:

  ```
  public partial class Page
  {
  public Page()
  {
      ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged += Page_PropertyChanged;
  }

  void Page_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      switch (e.PropertyName) {
      case "title":
          OnPropertyChanged("titleUI");
          break;
      }
  }

  public string titleUI
  {
      get { return title; }
      set
      {
          if (value == title)
              return;
          string oldValue = title;
          title = value;
          UndoRedo.PushAtomic(
              () => title = oldValue, 
              () => title = value,
              "change page title");
      }
  }

  ...
  ```

I used to listen to FrameworkElement.SourceUpdated for this purpose, but I abandoned this approoach to follow the MVVM design pattern more closely.

Is there a better or simpler approach?

**edit:** The reason I don't bind the TextBox to the `title` property directly is that I don't want to add to the undo-redo stack anytime the property is updated by something else than the TextBox. Also, when an EF ObjectContext materializes entities, the values are assigned by the setter and I don't want to add that to the undo-redo stack either.

**edit 2:** I've kinda given up on SO for this question. I'd delete it if I could. For example, I fail to grasp how the comments about my code being not true MVVM have anything to do with the issue at hand. Whether or not I make the entities classes strictly separated from the so called ViewModel classes, I would still have to find a way to "intercept" updates from the UI. I voted to close. Please do the same if you feel like me that this is going nowhere.

Comment: Seems a strange approach here - am I right in that you have a mixed model/viewmodel? It looks like Page is your Model but you are just extending the Page class as your ViewModel by using the partial?

Comment: Yes the ViewModel would be the "extension" of the generated class (which would be the Model).

Comment: Ok technically I wouldn't call that a viewmodel - it's more like a rich model - is there a reason you can't bind to the Title property? Since you are pretty much making a rich model you might as well use it's properties

Comment: See this is the problem I have with MVVM - the fact that you end up re-implementing everything in the VM. There are frameworks which give you a rich (generated) model which then allow you to expose this via the VM. This way you can bind to properties on the model instead of re-implementing them in the viewmodel. In your case it might be worth using something like Unity/Ninject to hook the property changed events - this way you can inject code into the generated code without having to re-implement everything. I don't like the way this code looks, it would give me a headache

Comment: @Charleh: I have to ask: why couldn't the file separation of a class be perceived as a Model/ViewModel separation? On what are you basing this affirmation?

Comment: Like @Charleh, I'm not sure you are following the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Technically the traditional viewmodel is a separate class since your Page class is really your model. The whole reason for MVVM is separation of concern - if you are putting your viewmodel code into the model class you technically only have a rich model because you can't apply another viewmodel to that model (your model essentially becomes the viewmodel and your therefore is tightly coupled with it). Here's some reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx take a look at their class diagrams and notice how it's structured

Comment: Added some more info in my answer

Answer (score 1):

wpf textbox has a builtin undo/redo - so if you just bind your viewmodel property with mode=twoway your viewmodel and your view is always in sync and your textbox handle the redo undo. do i miss something?

Comment: the drawback with my answer is that the redo/undo stack is deleted when you set the Property from anywhere else but the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer you wanted but I'd look at something like Unity:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/03/21/interception-in-silverlight-demo.aspx

This is a silverlight post (but it works in WPF too etc). Basically you can create an interceptor for your model and inject code into the property getter/setter. This way you can call your N-level undo/redo handling code without having to re-implement the properties.

Still what you are doing looks more like a rich model than a viewmodel since a standard viewmodel would encapsulate the model

I'd hate to have to write an additional property getter/setter with that code for every single property on the model

(they show a virtual method interceptor but it's possible to use an instance interceptor, I think this would work but listen to the points they make about interceptors and the scope they 'listen' in)

Edit:

Sorry for not really answering the question

Here are some suggestions:

I'm not sure if EF let's your entity classes derive from a base class but that would be one thing to look at - you would just hook the PropertyChanged event in the base class and handle accordingly. You could keep a `Dictionary<string, object>` on the base to track 'old' values and handle the undo

I understand the bit about EF materializing the object - can you not add a flag on the UndoRedo stack which tells it to disregard any property changes whilst the object is being materialized?

There must be some methods that you can override in your partial entity class to tell the stack to bypass any undo/redo info

Comment: Not sure - not used MEF myself but a quick Google didn't bring up any interesting results

Comment: Only thing I could find was: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650670.aspx  which says that MEF lacks interception entirely (but it's from March 2011)